# How to ensure a function is executed before a console.log in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I Have a function `findUser` which I am trying to Implement using `sails`,`MongoDb` and `mongoose` which is as follows:

```
  findUser(userId);

  function findUser(user_id){
    User.findOne({
            _id: user_id
        }).exec(function (err, userdata){
         //Some Logic
    });
  }
    console.log("XYZ");
```

Here `User` is a Model on which I am performing a `findOne` operation for a particular `_id` based on the `user_id` received by `findUser` function  .On running in `node Inspector` I found out that my `console.log` statement is getting printed before the completion of my `findUser` function. My Question is how can ensure that my `findUser` function is executed first and then my `console.log is` printed in mongoose?

Comment: Note that your code example doesn't actually include a call to `findUser`. (I assume it should be between the function definition and the `console.log` call.) Have you tried putting your `console.log` call inside of the `exec` callback?

Comment: done with the edit. My Question is If I Have a console.log outside as my requirement How do you ensure your findUser executes first and then my console.log?I don't want to put my console.log in function. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `console.log` within your exec callback.

This is due to Node.js and the fact that it is operating asynchronously. It runs both the `User.findOne` and `console.log()` functions simultaneously, and doesn't wait for the data from MongoDB call to return. Within the exec promise itself, the code is run synchronously, therefore putting console.log within the exec function will solve the issue.

```
function findUser(user_id){
  User.findOne({_id: user_id})
      .exec(function (err, userdata){
         //Some Logic
         console.log("XYZ")        
      });
};
```

Comment: Hi nickbdyer Is there another way to ensure that findOne is executed first and then console.log is executed?

Comment: Very interested to understand why you wouldn't want the `console.log()` inside the `.exec`. Outside of callbacks and pipes, I don't think theres much you can do. If you wanted to really get hipster, you could use some ECMA262 async/await syntax with a regenerator to convert it back to ES5.